# No data extrated. why?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

Java & SQL experts, when I run this jsp page I don't receive any data extracted into the table? What could be the reason ? I receive sort of a blank page with a four column table as highlighted below. No data is being retrieved from the database, why ?
I'm wondering whether the problem comes from the spacing in the double colons in the line codes below. When I eliminate the space in between the double colons I receive an error message.

```
<sql : query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
 SELECT * from Employees;
</sql : query>
```

**SELECT * from Employees;

Emp ID      Age     First Name      Last Name**

here is the program:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*" %>  
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>  

<html>
<head>
    <title>SELECT operation</title>
</head>
<body>
<sql : setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP"
     user="root" password="password"/>

<sql : query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
 SELECT * from Employees;
</sql : query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm receiving an empty html/jsp table with no data extracted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838507/im-receiving-an-empty-html-jsp-table-with-no-data-extracted)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*" %>  
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>  

<html>
<head>
    <title>SELECT operation</title>
</head>
<body>
<sql : setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP"
     user="root" password="password"/>

<sql : query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
 SELECT id,age,first,last from Employees;
</sql : query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```