# I'm receiving an empty html/jsp table with no data extracted

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I made a post four days back on this same forum seeking for a solution, but I have been checking for any solutions but in vain. I'm really stack as I can't continue mastering JSP which is a very big parcel for my 2014 plan of web programming. I'm new to JSP and database access ... so I'm requesting for your help.

**The problem:**
I have a simple my MySQL database and have designed a JSP page to display extracted data from the database. I tried and tested it via the command line and yes, the data is perfectly extracted. However the returning JSP page displays an empty html table with the four column headers ,with something similar to the one **below:**

```
SELECT * from Employees;  
ID   Age  First Name  Last Name
```

**Below is the database info:**

```
database - 'EMP'.  
table -  'Employees'.  
Columns; id; age; first; last.  
data;   100; 28; Zaid; Khan.      
password - 'password'
```

**Below is the JSP code:**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*, java.util.*, java.sql.*" %>  
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*, javax.servlet.*" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>  

<html>
<head>
    <title>SELECT operation</title>
</head>
<body>
<sql : setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP"
     user="root" password="password"/>

<sql : query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
 SELECT * from Employees;
</sql : query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However I'm suspicious with the code below (I extracted the code form the JSP program code), as when i try to close the gaps before and after the double colons (:) of the custom tags I receive a run time error message.

```
<sql : setDataSource  
<sql : query dataSource  
</sql : query>
```

**Below is the root folder and classpath:**

```
JSP page: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\jsp pages\RegName.jsp  

CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar 

JAVA_HOME: C:\glassfish3\jdk  

Path:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin; C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin 
Browser access of JSP: http://localhost:8080/jsp pages/FirstExample.jsp
```

**Below is the command line mysql info:**

```
Enter password: ********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.0.41-community-nt MySQL Community Edition (GPL)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql>
```

Comment: I hope you have followed the [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_query_tag.htm), but post the complete error stacktrace for diagnose the problem.

Comment: It worked very perfectly. All you need to do is copy the code in above URL and add `jstl 1.2` and `mysql connector` jar files in your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and clean your project then run again.

Comment: Kindly do us a favor, please do delete all the related questions posted [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823448/no-data-extracted-from-mysql-database-while-running-my-jsp-page), [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819753/no-data-extrated-why) by you.

Answer (score 0):

By default `mysql` port is **3306**, can you check by changing url as below?
 `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMP"`

Comment: @ Vinoth, thanx but no change still I receive an empty html table.

Comment: @ Vinoth Krishna , thanx you are my hero, after twisting the .jar files one by one I ended up putting all the files in my original folder: Tomcat7.0\lib\.... and there it was working.

Answer (score 0):

There will not be any space between the sql and (:) you need to keep like this,

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
 user="root"  password="pass123"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>
```

All you need to do is add `jstl 1.2` and `mysql connector` jar files in your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and clean your project then run again.

Comment: @ Vinoth I have been using this root folder: CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib but just found out one that is:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\lib which I guess could be the right folder. Let me add the .jar file and re-run the project. I will post my verdict immediately.

Comment: Mark this as accepted answer if it worked, so everyone will get the benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<tr>
<td>${row.id}</td>
<td>${row.age}</td>
<td>${row.first}</td>
<td>${row.last}</td>
```

Comment: thanks but there was no change... however I have got the  solution from Vinoth.